# Filter the logcat?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write the logcat to a file. This is working fine but my filtering does not seem to be working.

```
        try {
            //File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/logfile.log");
            File filename = new File("/storage/sdcard1/logfile.log");
            filename.createNewFile();
            String[] cmd = new String[] { "logcat", "-f", filename.getAbsolutePath(), "-v", "time", "*:W *:S" };
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am trying to filter it so it only shows the following type of lines:

```
07-07 20:25:23.507    1834-1834/com.test.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 20:25:23.507    1834-1834/com.test.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Which I think are the "W" lines? Which is why I tried to filter it using  "*:W *:S"? How can I filter it to just get lines like the ones above?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do either filter the logcat file or you want to write the logcat to a file because before you have asked another question for Saving the logcat to a file and now you want to filter.Please use a different question do not edit it here itself

Comment: I did ask this as a separate question so not sure what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using:

String[] cmd = new String[] { "logcat", "-f", filename.getAbsolutePath(), "-v", "time", "*:W" };